# surface area of a prism with some missing lengths

Tags: measurement-theory

**Question:**

A prism has an equilateral  triangular base with a perimeter of $12c$m. If the length of the prism is $24cm$, determine the total surface area of the prism.

**hint:** What is the area of 1 triangle?

I have draw a diagram and tried a few methods to figure out the area of 1 triangle, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The length of an arete of an equilateral triangle with a perimeter of $12$ is $a=4$.
Let us determine the height $h$ of a triangle : it is given by the trigonometric relation$$h=a\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=a\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
 $$ since the angles of an equilateral triangle are all $\frac{\pi}{3}$.
So the area of $1$ triangle is $$A=\frac{ah}{2}=a^{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}=4\sqrt{3}.
 $$ 
Now the total surface area of the prism is the sum of $2$ such triangle areas and the $3$ surfaces of the lateral faces.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the problem in simpler tasks:

- [Look the a triangular prism is made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_prism).
- You can observe that its surface is made of 3 rectangles and 2 triangles.
- Make questions about data you have in order to solve the problem:
- What is the total surface given 3 rectangles and 2 triangles? The sum of their surfaces!
- What is the surface of a generic rectangle? Base $\cdot$ height
- What is the surface of a generic triangle? Also Base $\cdot$ height

  - How can I calculate it? Pythagorean theorem. The height of a triangle intersects the base in the middle. So the height = $\sqrt{\text{side}^2 - (\frac{\text{side}}{2})^2 } $
- So the remaining part of the remaining part of the problem is to put all data together...

the part that I leave to you...